# Ansible community.vmware.vmware_guest_instant_clone fails with Folder not found

Tags: ansible, vmware

I can't figure how to set folder variable for community.vmware.vmware_guest_instant_clone module.
I've tried all the combinations for the folder variable and I get the "Folder not found." error every time.

By using the module community.vmware.vmware_vm_info I get VM folder in shape of:

```
/datacenter/vm/folder
```

If I use this folder path in instant clone module it fails.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Give us more than that.  Show the entire play, and the error output.

Comment: I've rechecked my variables, fixed them, rerun the script and it works great now.